# Why does the output log contain RequestId and TraceId?

Tags: serilog

Why does the output log contain RequestId and TraceId?[vs2019 quickwatch image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s9tJe.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a good [overview of what the purpose is, see this article](https://nblumhardt.com/2019/10/serilog-in-aspnetcore-3/).

Those are the [ASP.NET request correlation identifiers](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/aspnet/improvements-in-net-core-3-0-for-troubleshooting-and-monitoring-distributed-apps/) which the integration adds for correlation purposes.

Comment: interesting, so It looks like dotnet core has implemented distributed log tracking?